# build a dynamic string from vault KV values

Tags: go, consul-template

I'm trying to create something similar to this:

```
{{with secret "secret/data"}}
    {{range $k, $v := .Data}}
        {{if eq $k "db-primary"}}
            {{with $secret := secret "mysql-$v/creds/primary"}}
                {{$secret.username}}:{{$secret.password}}
            {{end}}
        {{end}}
    {{end}}
{{end}}
```

where `$v` is a dynamic value. I can't figure out how to have the nested `with` statement parse the vlaue of `$v` into its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer if anyone is looking to do something similar

```
{{with secret "secret/data"}}
    {{range $k, $v := .Data}}
        {{if eq $k "db-primary"}}
            {{with $secret := secret (printf "mysql-%s/creds/primary" $v)}}
                {{$secret.username}}:{{$secret.password}}
            {{end}}
        {{end}}
    {{end}}
{{end}}
```

using `printf` lets me replace and inject the value dynamically.